# linux find -exec two commands and concatenate on same line

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I have the following command:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name description -exec stat -c "%n --RDD-- %z" {} \; -exec head -1 {} \;
```

This finds all the description files 3 folders deep ands outputs something like:

```
/home/user/public_html/.git/description --RDD-- 2014-12-17 17:02:09.347983909 +0000
Some description
/home/user/public_sub/.git/description --RDD-- 2014-12-17 17:02:09.347983909 +0000
Another description
```

I would like to concatenate the two execs and get something like:

```
/home/user/public_html/.git/description --RDD-- 2014-12-17 17:02:09.347983909 +0000 --RDD-- Some description
/home/user/public_sub/.git/description --RDD-- 2014-12-17 17:02:09.347983909 +0000 --RDD-- Another description
```

I have been trying to get this done for the past day but cannot figure out a how to do it past this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--printf` in `stat` to avoid printing newline like this:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name description \
      -exec stat --printf="%n --RDD-- %z --ROD-- " {} \; -exec head -1 {} \;
```

OR else you can use `bash -c` and a command line in your command:

```
find ~ -maxdepth 3 -type f -name description -exec bash -c \
     'f="$1"; stat -c "%n --RDD-- %z --ROD-- $(head -1 "$f")" "$f"' - {} \;
```

Comment: Didn't spot the printf in help. Thank you